# How to count something in a mysql procedure?

Tags: mysql

I have written a procedure that shows me the image path from picture table and I want to  calculate the no. of unread messages.Here is what i am doing

```
CREATE PROCEDURE datehate.dashboard_message(IN UserID INT)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  picture.path_thumb,status
        FROM    picture,message,user_profile
        WHERE   (
                    (message.receiver_user_id=UserID)
                    AND
                    (user_profile.user_id=message.sender_user_id AND picture.picture_id=user_profile.picture_id)
                );
END
```

And this the output i am getting

```
path_thumb                                                  status

E:\DateOrHateUser\DEMO_2_Stockhlom\images\Male\1#j...   UNREAD
E:\DateOrHateUser\DEMO_2_Stockhlom\images\Male\3#j...   READ
E:\DateOrHateUser\DEMO_2_Stockhlom\images\Male\5#j...   UNREAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
SELECT count(*)
```

to get the number of records returned
and put

```
status="UNREAD"
```

in your WHERE condition

Comment: But it is only giving me 1 row i want path_thumb as well as count

Comment: Not sure I understand but don't you want to do two SELECT?

Comment: You can also use `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` after the first SELECT

Comment: It gives me  
path_thumb                                     unread_msgs
E:\DateOrHateUser\DEMO_2_Stockhlom\images\Male\1#j... 1
E:\DateOrHateUser\DEMO_2_Stockhlom\images\Male\5#j... 1

Answer (score 1):

How about -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE datehate.dashboard_message(IN UserID INT)
    BEGIN
        SELECT p.path_thumb, SUM(IF(m.status = 'UNREAD', 1, 0)) AS unread_msgs
        FROM message m
        INNER JOIN user_profile up
            ON m.sender_user_id = up.user_id
        INNER JOIN picture p
            ON up.picture_id = p.picture_id
        WHERE m.receiver_user_id=UserID
        GROUP BY m.sender_user_id, p.path_thumb;
    END
```

**EDIT** I have modified the above query to give the count of unread messages without excluding senders for whom you have no unread messages. Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

or this which will give you the count of messages in each status -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE datehate.dashboard_message(IN UserID INT)
    BEGIN
        SELECT p.path_thumb, m.status, COUNT(*) AS msgs
        FROM message m
        INNER JOIN user_profile up
            ON m.sender_user_id = up.user_id
        INNER JOIN picture p
            ON up.picture_id = p.picture_id
        WHERE m.receiver_user_id=UserID
        GROUP BY m.sender_user_id, p.path_thumb, m.status;
    END
```

Comment: Ya it is a good one but count does not return a correct value

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't return a correct value?  Please give an example.

Comment: It gives me  
path_thumb                                     unread_msgs
E:\DateOrHateUser\DEMO_2_Stockhlom\images\Male\1#j... 1
E:\DateOrHateUser\DEMO_2_Stockhlom\images\Male\5#j... 1

Comment: Which is what you asked for, is it not?  You said you wanted the number of unread messages.  Did you want the count of messages grouped by sender and status?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your question slightly and was being a bit slow. I think the updated version of the first query is what you were looking for.